# How to safely store a reference to owner in an owned C++ object?

Tags: c++, reference, unique-ptr, ownership-semantics

Class `Owner` owns multiple objects of class `Item` via `unique_ptr`. I want objects of `Item` to store a reference (not a pointer) to the `Owner` objects which owns them, with the following requirements:

1. There can never be a dangling reference.
2. The reference contained in an `itm` object of class `Item` never points to an `Owner` object which does not own `itm`.
3. An `Item` object always has an owner.
4. `Item` class will be used via its subclasses.

I tried automatically registering the objects of `Item` class during construction (in `Item::Item()`), but it leads to double deletion when they're created on the stack. Hence, I probably need to prevent them being created on the stack. But that's a problem when I am subclassing them. Is there an easier way of ensuring that the mutual links are always correct, without relaxing any of the requirements? I suspect that 3. might have to be relaxed, to enable creating the object first and registering it with the `Owner` later.

Comment: What is not clear in my question? Any suggestions of clarifications are more than welcome.

Comment: IMHO if the `Item`s are created on stack, and by stack I assume you mean they have automatic storage, then `Owner` doesn't really own them, at least resource-wise. Other that it seems that a reference to `Owner` in `Item` fits the bill.

Comment: Thanks. So in order to ensure that `Item` is always owned by `Owner`, I have to block automatic storage for `Item`?

Comment: If you make sure that only `Owner` is allowed to construct an `Item`, and that the reference is passed into the `Item` on construction all your points should be covered.

Comment: Are you *sure* an `Item` actually *needs* to store a back-reference? Or could that be provided by the way you access it?

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on my comment, if you make `Item`s constructor private, and take the reference to the owner on construction. Then you can make `Owner` a friend class, or as in my example make one of `Owner`s function a friend function.

This way `Item`s can only be created here and nowhere else. When they get created they get the reference to the `Owner` directly.

The reference in `Item` will always be valid, since when the `Owner` gets destroyed the `Item`s it owns are destroyed with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Item;

class Owner {
    public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> foos;

    void makeItem();
};

class Item {
    Item(Owner& b) : owner(b) {}

    friend void Owner::makeItem();
    Owner& owner;
};

void Owner::makeItem() {
    foos.emplace_back(new Item(*this));
}

int main() {
    Owner b;
    //Item item(b); not allowed, constructor is private
    b.makeItem();
}
```

Not completely sure what you mean with point 4.

Comment: I suspect, that `Foo` will be a base class. Your example will probably have to be adapted to allow creation of custom `Foo`s, but I guess mimicking `std`'s `emplace` is possible and relatively easy.

Comment: @luk32 You are probably right. It was not clear to me what OPs intention was for that or the usage of `Item`s so I left it out.